# TypeError: Cannot set property for while execution of passed the function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to functional programming. While passing function to another function in type script, I'm getting error. Here is my code: -

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public globals: Globals, public auth: AuthService, public placeService: PlaceService) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
    if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
      console.log(' userName ' + this.firstName + ' userName ' + this.userName + ' dp ' + this.dpUrl);
      this.fetchProfile();
      console.log(' userName ' + this.firstName + ' userName ' + this.userName + ' dp ' + this.dpUrl);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountries();
  }

  private firstName: any;
  private userName: any;
  private dpUrl: any;

  private fetchProfile() {
    this.auth.getProfileReponse(this.processResponse);
  }

  public processResponse(userResponse: Observable<HttpResponse<UserResp>>) {
    userResponse.subscribe(resp => {
      const user: User = { ...resp.body }.flatUser;
      console.log('user');
      console.log(user); // printing user perfetcly
      console.log(user.firstName); // printing user perfetcly
      this.firstName = user.firstName; // facing error here
      this.userName = user.userName;
      this.dpUrl = user.dpURL;
      // console.log(this.flatUser);
    });
  }
}
```

Error is as below:-

```
core.js:2090 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstName' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (navigation.component.ts:83)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
```

why this 'firstName' of undefined, I'm using angular 6 beta version. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the context of `this` that is undefined. Try this instead:

```
this.auth.getProfileReponse(() => this.processResponse);
```

The arrow syntax will bind to this, and it should prevent the error

Comment: it worked baba, you are beautiful. Thank you so much.